# Why does method chaining in TypeScript cause generic type inference to fail?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to build some sort of a "fluent API", and I also need to make use of generics, but TypeScript doesn't seem to like this combination!

Consider the following piece of code:

```js
class Foo<T> {
    abc(arg: T) {
        return this;
    }
    xyz(arg: T) {
        return this;
    }
}

function getFoo<T>() {
    return new Foo<T>();
}

// 1. Without method chaining:
let v1: Foo<string> = getFoo();
v1.abc(/* The type of the "arg" parameter here is "string", which means that the type was inferred correctly. */);

// 2. With method chaining:
let v2: Foo<string> = getFoo().abc(/* The type of the "arg" parameter here is "unknown", which obviously means the type was NOT inferred correctly. */);
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation of TypeScript?

Are there any workarounds to get method chaining to work with generic inference?

Answer (score 2):

The call on the right-hand side cannot use the type you declared in the left. It works if you instead pass the generic parameter in the call:

```
const foo = getFoo<string>().abc(...);
```

If you had to actually pass an an argument If the generic type, inference could also occur:

```
const foo = getFoo('foo').abc(...)
```

Comment: Well, sure, I already know that, I was asking why `The call on the right-hand side cannot use the type you declared in the left.`.

Comment: If you already know that (even though you didn't mention it), and that's not acceptable, then the answer is "no".

Comment: The whole point I was demonstrating in my question was just that. I didn't need a reiteration of the premise of my question. Furthermore, "no" is clearly not an answer to a "why" question.

Comment: You didn't ask a "why" question. You asked whether you're doing something wrong and whether there's a way to make it work. The answer to both is "no", except for what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: My answer demonstrates two solutions, one modifies how the function is called and the other modifies the function being called. If changing the code is "besides the point", the remaining answer is "fork the compiler", a clearly out of scope answer.

Comment: I've already made my point. However, I'm curious to know what exactly is wrong with the question that makes it deserve a downvote, as you gave it one?

Comment: Because you, at least in parts, asked the very clear question of "is there a workaround". Even if my answer doesn't contain the answer to a "why doesn't it work", regardless of whether you asked that or not, it still contains an answer to that question. However, you don't seem to accept changing either the called nor calling code, but you also don't specify what you deem an acceptable change. As such your question fails to communicate your expectations and you just shut down a well-intended answer. I'm also going to stop investing time at this point.

Comment: @Arad This is the correct answer to the question as stated. The fact that you, Arad, already knew the answer just shows that you didn't ask the right question. That doesn't change that it is the right answer to the question that you wrote.

Comment: To be clear, your question was *"Am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation of TypeScript?"* and the answer is that Typescript's generic inference is limited in the way stated in this answer. You didn't ask why Typescript is limited in this way.